# Chapter 8 Ruby On Rails by Michael Hartl. Authentication_pages_spec.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was doing chapter 8 of Ruby on Rails by Michael Hartl, I finished the chapter, finally ran my test and got a few errors. I checked if my codes were right by cross checking with Michael Hartl's github relevant files and also by viewing his recent screencast and yet I cannot seem to figure out the error.

Could you please kindly tell me the error and the solution like what I need to change?

ERRORS

2) Authentication signin with valid information

```
    ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { sign_in user }←[0m
     ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `redirect_back_or' for #<SessionsController:0x4366b
d8>←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'←[0m
←[36m     # (eval):2:in `click_button'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:13:in `sign_in'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:31:in `block (4 levels)
 in <top (required)>'←[0m
```

3) Authentication signin with valid information

```
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { sign_in user }←[0m
     ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `redirect_back_or' for #<SessionsController:0x43fdd
60>←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'←[0m
←[36m     # (eval):2:in `click_button'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:13:in `sign_in'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:31:in `block (4 levels)
 in <top (required)>'←[0m
```

4) Authentication signin with valid information

```
    ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { sign_in user }←[0m
     ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `redirect_back_or' for #<SessionsController:0x44773
38>←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'←[0m
←[36m     # (eval):2:in `click_button'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:13:in `sign_in'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:31:in `block (4 levels)
 in <top (required)>'←[0m
```

5) Authentication signin with valid information

```
    ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { sign_in user }←[0m
     ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `redirect_back_or' for #<SessionsController:0x4153f
f8>←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'←[0m
←[36m     # (eval):2:in `click_button'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:13:in `sign_in'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:31:in `block (4 levels)
 in <top (required)>'←[0m
```

6) Authentication signin with valid information

```
    ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { sign_in user }←[0m
     ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `redirect_back_or' for #<SessionsController:0x4347f
a8>←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'←[0m
←[36m     # (eval):2:in `click_button'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:13:in `sign_in'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:31:in `block (4 levels)
 in <top (required)>'←[0m
```

7) Authentication signin with valid information

```
    ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { sign_in user }←[0m
     ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `redirect_back_or' for #<SessionsController:0x43e1e
d8>←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'←[0m
←[36m     # (eval):2:in `click_button'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:13:in `sign_in'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:31:in `block (4 levels)
 in <top (required)>'←[0m
```

8) Authentication signin with valid information followed by signout

```
    ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { sign_in user }←[0m
     ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `redirect_back_or' for #<SessionsController:0x446dc
18>←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'←[0m
←[36m     # (eval):2:in `click_button'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:13:in `sign_in'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:31:in `block (4 levels)
 in <top (required)>'←[0m
```

**session_conrtoller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
       sign_in user
       redirect_back_or user
    else
       flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination"
       render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

**utilities.rb**

```
include ApplicationHelper

RSpec::Matchers.define :have_error_message do |message|
   match do |page|
    page.should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid')
  end
end

def sign_in(user)
  visit signin_path
  fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
  fill_in "Password", with: user.password
  click_button "Sign in"

  # Sign in when not using Capybara.
  cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```

**authentication_pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
  end

  describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
      it { should have_error_message }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_error_message }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { sign_in user }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
      it { should have_link('Settings',    href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Users',       href: users_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign in') }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It would be a little easier to help you debug if you reformatted your code so that it shows up as a code section here (prefix each line with at least 4 spaces) as well as removed all of the ANSI terminal codes from the terminal output (i.e. anything that looks like "←[0m ←[31m")

Comment: @Chrisbloom7 Apologies about the formatting. RSK was kind enough to re format it. You should be able to interpret the code more easier now. Any ideas what where the problem may lie in?

Comment: If you've debugged the issue successfully please update the status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed along to an earlier version of this project and like edr says, that method `redirect_back_or` was defined in app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb.
Please check to see that its there, then your app should run fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have undefined method(s) I would look for the offending logic in `redirect_back_or`.  debugging continues ....

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `redirect_back_or` method is defined in app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb.

Since you haven't listed that code above I'd start looking there.